# Concatenating within jquery build CSV string variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

What is the best way to concatenate in jquery to achieve "carid1|engineid1,carid2|engineid2" eg:"244|504,442|882"

```
$('#tblResults input[id*="ShowRoom"]').each(function(i, item){ 
strValue = $(this).attr("carid") + '|' + $(this).attr("engineid"); 

alert(strValue);

 }).get().join(",");
```

Below is the html

```
<TABLE width="100%" class="normal" id="tblResults" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
    <TBODY>
    <TR class=header>
    <TH class=sortLPad title="Sort by URN" onclick="reSort('0')" align=left>URN </TH>

    <TH class=sortLPad title="Sort by ShowRoom" onclick="reSort('5')" align=left>Show Room</TH></TR>

    <P></P>

    <TR EventId="504">
    <TD id=URN noWrap>23KV9878788</TD> 

    <TD id="ShowRoom" class=lPad><INPUT onfocusin=clearField(this); id="ShowRoom0" onfocusout=resetField(this); onkeypress=validate(this) maxLength=1 value=1 size=1 version="2000120420142859" elementname="ShowRoom" engineid="504" carid="244"></TD>

    </TR>

    <TR EventId="403">
    <TD id=URN noWrap>889878744</TD> 

    <TD id="ShowRoom" class=lPad><INPUT onfocusin=clearField(this); id="ShowRoom2" onfocusout=resetField(this); onkeypress=validate(this) maxLength=1 value=1 size=1 version="2000120420142859" elementname="ShowRoom" engineid="882" carid="442"></TD>

    </TR>

    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `.each` approach return the each `input` element you iterate; therefore `.get().join(',')` won't work.  Instead push the values into an array and then concatenate using `join(',')`.

```
var arr = [];
$('#tblResults input[id*="ShowRoom"]').each(function(i, item){ 
strValue = $(this).attr("carid") + '|' + $(this).attr("engineid");
    arr.push (strValue)
 });

console.log (arr.join (',')) // returns 244|504,442|882
```

Comment: @Regent it isn't about performance.  The above code posted by OP is not working as indented.  So I have shown him the way to do so.  BTW: if performance is priority I wouldn't even used `jQuery`

Comment: @Regent: I am new to javascript and jquery. Isn't jquery just used to optimize coding? i am shocked jquery that is so widely popular has performance issues :(

Comment: I misread OP's code from the beginning. I don't know why I thought that it looks like [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/7x41fL89/1/). About _even simpler_: I suspect difficult selector like `#tblResults input[id*="ShowRoom"]` will show small perfomance difference between jQuery and `querySelector`.

Comment: @Gauls jQuery is used for shorter and simpler code and for cross-browser compatability. That's all. Sometimes people use it even in places where non-jQuery will be shorter. It's all about user's experience and care about code's quality.